# Haskell: Desugaring State do notation

Tags: haskell

I have a contrived function to help calculate the Fibonacci sequence using `State`.

```
fbs :: Int -> State (Int,Int) Int
fbs = \_ -> do
  (a,b) <- get
  put (b,a+b)
  (a,_) <- get
  pure a
```

It compiles when I write it with do notation, but I can't desugar it:

```
fbs' :: Int -> State (Int, Int) Int
fbs' = \_ -> get >>= (\(a,b) ->
  put (b,a+b) *>
    get (\(a,_) ->
      pure a )) 

 * Ambiguous type variable `f0' arising from a use of `pure'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Missing `>>=` after last `get`?

Comment: Why is fbs taking a parameter which it always ignores?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Roughly put, each `do` line corresponds to `>>=` (or some of its simpler forms like `>>`).

In your case, you get:

```
fbs = \_ -> 
  get >>= ( \ (a,b) ->
     put (b,a+b) >>
        get >>= ( \ (a,_) ->
           pure a ))
```

I added some redundant parentheses and indentation for clarity.

Your original code lacks a `>>=` after the second `get`.